# java throws InvalidModuleDescriptorException when module exports patched package

Tags: java, java-9, java-10, java-module, java-platform-module-system

`java` 10.0.2+13 throws a `java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException` when a `module-info.class` in a directory in the module path exports a package that isn't under the same directory.

That is sensible behavior in many circumstances, but, in my case, I have the package under another directory which is patched into the module in question using `--patch-module`.

**Example:**

Module `m` is defined in file `classes/m/module-info.class`.

`m` exports package `p`.

`module-info.class` is the only child of directory `classes/m`.

Directory `classes/patch` contains `p/Main.class`.

Simplified command line:

```
java --module-path classes/m --patch-module m=classes/patch --module m/p.Main
```

The above will throw a `java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException` that says that "Package p not found in module".

Is there any way to get `java` to not throw an `InvalidModuleDescriptorException`, without having to copy the `class` files from `classes/m` & `classes/patch` into the same directory, or into the same `jar` file?

Comment: Can you share your project structure instead? ... and the reason along with what are you patching in the project?

Comment: I'm working on a Gradle plugin to support JPMS modules, so I'm trying to support many project structures. I'm patching because Kotlin compiles to one directory, and Java to another.

Comment: The existing Gradle `Task`s that run `java` (e.g., `Test`, `JavaExec`) use the output directories of the compile tasks instead of jars, and I'd like to leave their behavior unmodified as much as possible. If I can't prevent this exception via some `java` argument, I'll probably just depend on the `jar` outputs of the `Jar` tasks instead of the directory outputs of the compile tasks.

Comment: In my experience the `--patch-module` option doesn't take effect until _after_ the initial module resolution has taken place. This unfortunately means the exported package doesn't exist during the initial resolution because what you specify in `--patch-module` hasn't been applied yet.

Comment: @Slaw Yeah. Are there any other `java` options that get around this? I can remove the `--patch-module` option if the solution so requires.

Comment: Outside of moving everything, as you've already considered, into the same directory or JAR file? Unfortunately no, I'm not aware of another way.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for confirmation. I guessed that there wouldn't be any better solution than using jars, but I figured I'd ask, just to make sure…

Comment: Patching is complicated and the implementation requires the unpatched module to not have integrity issues before it is patched. In this case, the module claims to export p but there is no package p in the unpatched module. I'm curious how you got here because it should have failed at compile time. In any case, the only workaround is to put a placeholder/dummy resource in classes/m/p so that the set of packages matches the exports in the compiled module.

Comment: @AlanBateman I got here by using `—patch-module m=classes/patch` for `javac` when I compiled the `module-info.java` that produced `classes/m/module-info.class`

Comment: @AlanBateman If you're right and using a dummy resource file fixes what the OP is asking to fix and avoids what the OP is asking to avoid I think you should make that an answer :). Especially since the build tool being used could exclude the dummy file from the JAR when ready for packaging.

Comment: @XDR - thanks for comment on how you compile this. I think the example just highlights a differences between compile-time and run-time in how patching works. At run-time, patching can only be used to override classes/resources or augment in existing or additional packages - it does not support the case where the original module doesn't contain the exported and open packages that it claims to have. I'll create an issue in JBS on this but it needs a lot more consideration.

Comment: @Slaw - a dummy resource will work so if someone has cycles to write this workaround as an answer then go for it. I note your previous comment where you said that patches are processed post-resolution. This isn't so as the patches have to be scanned before resolution in order to find out the complete set of packages in the module. The strange scenario in this post is that module-info.class has been compiled to a different directory rather than the output directory where the classes for the module are. The result is not a valid exploded module.

Comment: @AlanBateman Maybe "post-resolution" is the wrong word but the `--patch-module` command must be _applied_ after initial integrity checks have already taken place. Otherwise you'd be able to patch a module from an invalid state to a valid one.

Comment: @AlanBateman Thanks.  I assume JBS is "Java Bug System".  You probably already saw my feature request there (https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8210151).

Comment: While a placeholder for the package answers my initial question, I prefer to use a jar instead for my use case…